# Looping over plots

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I try to generate a lot of plots and save them in separate files. Each plot should be based on a variable from a dataframe.

This works when using the numbers of the variables:

```
for(i in names(df)[19:20]) {
   png(paste(i, "png", sep = "."), width = 400, height = 400)
   print(ggplot(df) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x= i), binwidth= 0.4) +   
   theme_bw())
   dev.off()
}
```

However, it doesn't work if I'm using variable names instead of the ordered number. I don't understand why.

```
for(i in names(df)[c("varname1","varname2","varname3")]) {
   png(paste(i, "png", sep = "."), width = 400, height = 400)
   print(ggplot(df) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x= i), binwidth= 0.4) +            
   theme_bw())
   dev.off()
}
```

I get the following error message at the latter question (if it's exactly the same variable as in the first example):

"Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"? "

Any ideas?

Comment: use `for( i in c("varname1","varname2","varname3")){ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`names(df)` is an unnamed vector, so it doesn't make sense to select named values from that vector.

What you're looking for is

```
for(i in c("varname1","varname2","varname3")) {
   png(paste(i, "png", sep = "."), width = 400, height = 400)
   print(ggplot(df) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x= i), binwidth= 0.4) +            
   theme_bw())
   dev.off()
}
```