# Looping over boxplots (dataframe columns)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, boxplot

I tried to generate a lot of boxplots and save them in separate files. Each boxplot should be based on a variable from a dataframe. I more or less tried to "copy" the solution of: [Looping over plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137370/looping-over-plots), but that doesn't work.

```
for(i in c("varname1","varname2")) {
  png(paste(i, "png", sep = "."), width = 400, height = 400)
  print(ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes_string(y =seq_along(i)  , x = i)) +    
  theme_bw()) 
  dev.off()
}
```

I searched for a solution an this site as well, but couldn't find something that works.

Comment: a base r boxplot loop would also be fine: `boxplot(dataframe$varname)`

Comment: What is the exact error message or problem, please? _but that doesn't work_ is quite vague.

Comment: Do the plots need to live in separate files? This sounds like a great opportunity for `facet`...

Comment: @UweBlock: sorry. It displayed an horizontal line.

Comment: @AndrewCheesman: Interesting, I didn't knew about the facet option! It doesn't need to be in separate files. One file would be optimal. However, facet seems to work with subgroups. In my case, it are just separate variables to be displayed.

Comment: @placebo Hmm, sounds strange. Need to see some sample data which reproduce the error (see [mcve] for guidance). Please, [edit] your Q and add the result of `dput(df)` -- but only if it's sufficiently small. Thank you.

Comment: @placebo Your reply to  @Andrew's comment on _facets_ may indicate that your data is stored in _wide_ format. `ggplot2` works best with data in _long_ format. -- Another reason to have a look at your data.

Comment: @placebo You can use `melt()` in the `reshape` package to format your data so that ggplot will facet it correctly. You want to transform multiple fields (wide format) into a single value field differentiated by a classifier field (long format). `ggplot` likes this format for more than just facet, as well - it's worth learning. One overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250872/reshaping-data-to-plot-in-r-using-ggplot2

Comment: @AndrewCheesman and UweBlock: you are right! The data is saved in wide format. It's a bit cumbersome to reshape the data, but I'll give it a try. I gust tried `gather()` in the `tidyr` package, but that leads to problems because some data is stored in POSIXlt format. But I'll read the overview and will try to convert it. Facet looks like a great option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. 'seq_along' should be removed.
I also changed some other things: I added "Hist." as a prefix in the filename, removed the visual elements in the x scale and removed missings to prevent warnings.

```
for(i in c("varname1", "varname2", "varname3")) {
png(paste("Hist",i, "png", sep = "."), width = 400, height = 400)
print(ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes_string(y=i, x = 0), na.rm=TRUE) + 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + xlab(NULL) + theme_bw())
dev.off()
}
```

What was a bit strange for me, is that ggplot somehow expects an X-variable. I ignored this by setting x to zero and hiding those elements in the visuals. So it's just a bit annoying.